# firebase npm tools install issue

Tags: npm-install, firebase-tools, npm-package

```
> npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\Desktop\'~\.npm-global'\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\.cache\firebase\runtime/shell.bat -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! '--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-09T22_29_32_163Z-debug-0.log
```

I need downloaded tools but i can't, someone can help me about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is happening in the protobufjs package, that seems to be used by firebase-tools. like you can see below.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\berk.BERK-PC\Desktop\'~\.npm-global'\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
```

Then this seems like the actual problem.

```
npm ERR! '--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

What I would do,
and since the error doesnt seem to be coming from the command you entered.

Update npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

Clear the cache

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Then try and reinstall again.

Node Version
npm Version